# Ordering by many to many attribute on Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a table of TransportationOrders. Every TransportationOrder has a Route.. and every Route has Places.

What I need is lo list All the TransportationOrders but sorted by the name of the first place I have to visit.

My Models simplified:

```
class TransportationOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    route = models.ManyToManyField(Place, through='PlaceHasTransportationOrder')


class PlaceHasTransportationOrder(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transportation_order = models.ForeignKey(TransportationOrder, related_name="route", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1) #This indicate the order of  visits
    date = models.DateField()

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    lon = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

I tried to define a method on TransportationOrder Model, but this doesn't work whe I try to http:///url?ordering=first_place_name 
because this ordering works on a database level. What option do I have?

```
def first_place_name(self):
    place = Place.objects.all().filter(placehastransportationorder__transportation_order=self, placehastransportationorder__order=1)
    return place[0].name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `order_by` method of Django QuerySets. I believe what you want is

```
TransportationOrder.order_by('routes__name').first()
```

or something similar.

As an example, I loaded your models into a one off using Django 1.10.5.

I created 5 objects: `p` and `p2` are `Place` entries, `t` is a `TransportationOrder`, and `pt` & `pt2` are `PlaceHasTransportationOrder` entries.

`p` was related to `t`, and `p2` was related to `pt2`. The `TransportationOrder` object `t` was used on both `pt` and `pt2`.

I named the `Place`'s "Testing" and "Alphabet", creating "Alphabet" second. This made it so that just a basic query on the `routes` field of `TransportationOrder` would return them in id order:

`t.first().routes.all().values_list('name')
<QuerySet [('Testing',), ('Alphabet',)]>`

Applying the `order_by` I mentioned above resulted in:

`t.order_by('routes__name').values_list('routes__name')
<QuerySet [('Alphabet',), ('Testing',)]>`

EDIT:

The output from the last statement lists the `TransportationOrder` objects in order by their `Place` names. I mistakenly narrowed the output to only output the values of the `routes__name` relationship pathway.

Comment: Very helpful answer, and I'm sorry for my bad explanation.  What I finnaly want is to list all my TransportationOrders, all of them. But sorted by the name of the Place that I have to visit first. (I'm going to edit trying to be more clear)

Comment: If you take the values_list call off my final output, that is the result you will get. I made the mistake of printing the places through the routes field, but the Transportation orders will be in the order you desire.